# Difficulty integrating YELP Checkout API. Not able to fetch opportunity_token

Tags: javascript, php, yelp, yelp-fusion-api

Referring to the [documentation](https://docs.developer.yelp.com/docs/checkout-api#section-i-frame-url-and-content)

The checkout API says to generate URL : `https://<partner_domain_path>/<partner_business_id>/?opportunity_token=<opportunity_token>&yelp_site=m&yelp_locale=en_US`

**"The partner_domain_path shall be pre-registered with Yelp"**. Which we have already registered.

We are confused with **"opportunity_token"** as which API will provide this to us.

https://docs.developer.yelp.com/docs/iframe-interactions : Referring to the Iframe integration, it is also asking for **opportunity_token**

Can anyone help referring the [documentation](https://docs.developer.yelp.com/docs/checkout-api#section-i-frame-url-and-content) what flow and API should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide [`opportunity_token`](https://docs.developer.yelp.com/docs/iframe-interactions#section-request-params), Yelp provides that.

It is a UUID that Yelp will pass in its request to your URL.

Fulfilling the iframe interaction API requires you to have a route that serves requests to `https://<partner_domain_path>/<partner_business_id>/`

Yelp also forwards `yelp_site` and `yelp_locale` to your site so that you can decide what experience to serve the user.

Your site can retrieve `opportunity_token` from the request query params and used that to carry out more requests to Yelp API.